# Need help with inotifywait loop only processing one file

Tags: scripts, inotify

I have created a shell script that runs an inotifywait command.

It watches a folder for new image uploads (That comes from a website) and then uses Imagemagick to resize them, move them to another directory and then sends a command to a remote wordpress installation to import the images.

It looks like this (I've created it as a service, so it runs at startup)

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET=/var/www/img/uploads
PROCESSED=/var/www/img/processed
DONE=/var/www/img/finished
URL=https://--censored--

inotifywait -m -r -e create -e moved_to --format "%f" $TARGET \
        | while read FILENAME
                do
                        echo Detected $FILENAME, moving and resizing
                        mv "$TARGET/$FILENAME" "$PROCESSED/$FILENAME"
                        convert -verbose -debug coder -log %e "$PROCESSED/$FILENAME" -resize 600x600 -background white -gravity center -extent 600x600 "$DONE/$FILENAME"
                        wp @mm media import "$URL/$FILENAME" --path=--censored--
                        echo Finished processing $FILENAME.
                done
```

The code is working, but if I upload multiple files it only uploads the first one.
If I remove the Wordpress part it seems to process all files.

But I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `inotifywait` command generates a correct list of filenames, separated by newlines?

Comment: In the log file it seems only one file is generated and processed. If I then wait and upload a new one it works. But if I upload two just after each other only one is processed. But I'm not sure how to check if each is created on new lines?

Comment: Instead of piping it to the wp loop, write it to a temporary file to see what goes on, like this: `inotifywait -m -r -e create -e moved_to --format "%f" $TARGET > my.log.file`, then upload multiple images, then look at the output of the `inotifywait` process in `my.log.file`.

Comment: It creates two separate lines - I just tried to simoultaniously add two files and the output in the log is

file1.jpg
file2.jpg

I'm wondering if it is because the file transfer happens to fast, and it can't see all the changes? Can I add a pause or something like that?

Comment: I believe you need to run `inotifywait` itself in a loop, as described here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait, Example 2.

Comment: `inotifywait` waits for a Single event, and reports on it. Read `man -k inotify`.

Comment: Ended up dividing the script into two separate processes so one for the convert and one for the upload. Setting a "sleep" before done in the process script seems to have been enough for the next event to happen. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: @MadsK feel free to write an Answer (box below) with your solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up dividing the script into two separate processes so one for the convert and one for the upload. Setting a "sleep" before done in the process script seems to have been enough for the next event to happen. Thanks for the answers.